# Why the symbols for cards is not showed ( hearts, spades, diamonds, clubs) when I run the program?

Tags: c++, static-cast

//This program first set 52 cards with their number and their Suit and then it displays them. After that it shuffles the cards and swaps them with random cards and display them. But problem is that while displaying the cards the symbol of their suit is not displayed. Why??
Please help someone!!!
PS: In the deck of cards the numbering of cards starts from 2. Because Ace has been assigned 14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // for srand(), rand()
#include <ctime>   // for time for srand()
using namespace std;

enum Suit
{
    clubs,
    diamonds,
    hearts,
    spades
};

const int jack = 11; // from 2 to 10 are integers without names
const int queen = 12;
const int king = 13;
const int ace = 14;

class card
{
private:
    int number; // 2 to 10, jack, queen, king, ace
    Suit suit;  // clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades
public:
    card() // constructor
    {
    }

    void set(int n, Suit s) // set card
    {
        number = n;
        suit = s;
    }

    void display(); //  function declaration ; display card
};

void card ::display() // display() definition; this function displays the card
{
    if (number >= 2 && number <= 10)
        cout << number;
    else
        switch (number)
        {
        case jack:
            cout << "J";
            break;
        case queen:
            cout << "Q";
            break;
        case king:
            cout << "K";
            break;
        case ace:
            cout << "A";
            break;
        }

    switch (suit)
    {

    case clubs:
        cout << static_cast<char>(5);
        break; // here is the problem
    case diamonds:
        cout << static_cast<char>(4);
        break; // it does not displays
    case hearts:
        cout << static_cast<char>(3);
        break; // the symbol of Suit
    case spades:
        cout << static_cast<char>(6);
        break; // for all types of cards
    }
}

int main()
{
    card deck[52];
    int j;
    cout << endl;

    for (j = 0; j < 52; j++) // makes an ordered deck
    {
        int num = (j % 13) + 2; // cycles through 2 to 14, 4 times
        Suit su = Suit(j / 13); // cycles through 0 to 3, 13 times
        deck[j].set(num, su);   // set card
    }

    cout << "\nOrdered deck:\n";
    for (j = 0; j < 52; j++) // display ordered deck
    {
        deck[j].display();
        cout << "  ";
        if (!((j + 1) % 13)) // newline every 13 cards
            cout << endl;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));       // seed random numbers with time
    for (j = 0; j < 52; j++) // for each card in the deck,
    {
        int k = rand() % 52; // pick another card at random
        card temp = deck[j]; // and swaps them
        deck[j] = deck[k];
        deck[k] = temp;
    }

    cout << "\nShuffled deck:\n";
    for (j = 0; j < 52; j++) // display shuffled deck
    {
        deck[j].display();
        cout << "  ";
        if (!((j + 1) % 13)) // newline every 13 cards
            cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;

} // end main()
```

Comment: What leads you to the belief that shoving integer values 5,4,3, and 6 as characters, will display card symbols. If your terminal is intent on supporting that, so be it, but if it isn't, then... [ascitable.com](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Why are you converting them to `char`? `cout << 5;` will print `5` just fine.

Comment: @Quimby He wants ♣, ♦, ♥, ♠

Comment: Does modern Windows still support the [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) graphical characters? I wouldn't count on it, and i n any case it certainly would apply to MacOS or Linux. I would recommend using  UTF-8 encoding, instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right. I want these symbols ♣, ♦, ♥, ♠. But how can I get these??

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA I tried both. But it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "wouldn't apply", i.e., Linux and MacOS wouldn't support code page 437 at all.

Comment: Can you please tell me that where I can get the table for this???
@Schol-R-LEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (suit)
{
    case clubs:
        cout << "\u2663"; 
        break; 
    case diamonds:
        cout << "\u2666";
        break;
    case hearts:
        cout << "\u2665";
        break;
    case spades:
        cout << "\u2660"; 
        break;
}
```